# Пара вопросов по Novell под Windows

Tags: база-данных, сеть

Учусь на программиста на заочке. Через год ВКР. Работаю на машиностроительном заводе, хочу чтобы программа, после защиты, использовалась в моей реальной работе. Приложение задумывается сетевым, человек на 5, работающих в одном кабинете. На заводе сеть Novell. Я в ней вообще ничего не понимаю. Её плюсы и минусы мне неведомы.
Например, на складе 4 кладовщицы. Документы печатаются в программе своей (не моей) разработки. Компы есть у каждой. А печатать может только одна кладовщица, МФУ подключено к её компьютеру. Прошу админов (ОЧЕНЬ ленивых) расшарить МФУ на остальных трёх кладовщиц. Отвечают - под этой сетью нельзя, надо ставить сетевое МФУ, а оно дорогое, начальство не согласует. Это админы мне мозги любят или действительно так?
Вопрос в основном такой - какую СУБД применить, чтобы удалось моей программе работать под этой сетью? СУБД, само собой, открытую. Смотрю в сторону PostgreSQL.
Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *Отвечают - под этой сетью нельзя, надо ставить сетевое МФУ, а оно дорогое, начальство не согласует.* Брехня. В NDS регистрируется принтер (создаются объекты Workstation и Printer) создаётся объект "Print Queue", к ней цепляется созданный принтер как обслуживающее устройство и учётные записи нужных пользователей как клиенты, и формируются права доступа. Соответственно очередь появляется на рабочих станциях как сетевой принтер, можно печатать. Или по старинке - на станции с принтером расшарить принтер (возможно, включив соотв. службы) и подключиться к нему (Netware Client этому не мешает).

Comment: @Akina Интересно, это чудо под вендой все еще под IPX работает?

Comment: @gbg Зависит от версии сервера (уже в 5 версии была введена нативная поддержка IP) и идиотизма админа. Впрочем, в локалке IPX ничем не хуже IP, а в некоторых моментах даже лучше.

Comment: @Akina - да, но идиотизм мог дойти до того, чтобы полностью вырубить TCP/IP. И если это так, найти СУБД, способную работать через IPX в 2020х будет большим квестом

Comment: @gbg В версии 5 и старше вырубить IP нельзя - на нём работает ядро. А найти современную СУБД, которая будет работать на 4.12 или младше - вот это действительно квест, причём скорее всего нерешаемый. Если же СУБД будет работать на другом сервере - то какая разница, какая версия Нетвари?

Comment: @Akina никакой, но ответ обнадеживает  - ОП может хотя бы попробовать использовать что-то современное.

Comment: @gbg Если же Netware более-менее свежая - то это уже не Netware server, а Netware services, работающий поверх SUSE Linux. А там с сервером печати вообще не должно быть проблем, равно как и с сервером БД.

Comment: Круто! Даже не ожидал, что сразу будет комментарий прямо по сути реализации желаемого в такой немолодой штуке, как netware. А может, революционное решение: нафиг неваре, построить одноранговую сеть из виндовых машин? И всё сделать в рамках этой сети?

Comment: Оно бы всё хорошо, я даже за. Но у нас на клиентских машинах закрыто админом всё, вплоть до смены обоев и времени. Чую, бодаться с админами придётся с привлечением высокого начальства.